# Exiting from loop in Java Script when next time that function is called

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, loops

> I am creating dashboard (graphs). That will update for every 3 seconds.
>   The following is the sample html buttos of my code,

```
 <input type = "button" name = "cpuLoad" value = "CPU Load" onclick="getData('CPU')"/>
  <br></br>
  <input type = "button" name = "HeapMemory" value = "Heap Memory" onclick="getData('HEAP_MEMORY')"/>
  <br></br>
```

> when click cpuLoad i need cpu metrics from data base, and Heap memory for Heap memory metrics.
>   This my getData function in java script,

```
async function getData(per) { 
  var type = document.form1.types.value;
  var state = 'live';
  if(state == "live"){
      setInterval(async function(){
           let data =  await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api?type=${per}&state=${state}`);
           json = await data.json(); 
           await formatting(json, per, type);
        }, 3000);     
}
```

> Actually when click one button it will work correctly. it will updated each 3 seconds. but when i click next button then the loop for the first request won't stop. both requests will be running(both loops running at a time). I see both graphs in my html alternatively. this is wrong.
>   when i click next button or next request i want exit from the previous running loop. i need output of only the current request. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use clearInterval to stop your existing setInterval. I think the following code should work for you.

```
var runningInterval = null;
async function getData(per) { 
  var type = document.form1.types.value;
  if(runningInterval != null)
      clearInterval(runningInterval);
  runningInterval = setInterval(async function(){
           let data =  await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api?type=${per}&state=${state}`);
           json = await data.json(); 
           await formatting(json, per, type);
        }, 3000);      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to cancel an already repeating `setInterval` you can use `clearInterval`

read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval